# Why child exception is not found?

Tags: php, class, exception, inheritance

I have a child exception that inherit of his parent that extends to the Exception class :

```php
namespace Exceptions;
    
use Exception;
    
class InvalidFieldException extends Exception
{
}
    
class UsernameWrongFormatException extends InvalidFieldException
{
  const USERNAME_MESSAGE_ERROR_WRONG_FORMAT = "Oops ! Merci de suivre le format ci-dessous pour votre nom d'utilisateur !";
}
```

```php
namespace Controller;
    
use Model\User;
use Model\UserModel;
use Enumeration\UserType;
// use Exceptions\EmptyFieldException;
use Exceptions\FileTypeException;
use Exceptions\InvalidFieldException;
use Exceptions\UsernameWrongFormatException;
// use Exceptions\InvalidFieldException;
```

A controller that use the exception :

```php
readonly class UserController
{
  public function __construct(private User $user)
  {
  }

  public function handleUsernameField(string $username)
  {    
    $userRegex =  "/^[A-Z][A-Za-z\d]{2,10}$/";
    if (!empty($username)) {
      if (preg_match($userRegex, $username)) {
        return ["username" => $username];
      }
      header("HTTP/1.1 400");
         
      throw new UsernameWrongFormatException();
    }
    header("HTTP/1.1 400");
    //  throw new
    EmptyFieldException(
      EmptyFieldException::USERNAME_MESSAGE_ERROR_EMPTY
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using a condition in the index.php file to check which exception is raised up but I still not understand why nothing is working :

```php
switch ($action) {
  case "sign_up":
    try {
      $template = "sign_up.twig";
      $paramaters["message"] = $userController->signUpValidator(
        $_POST['username'],
        // $_FILES['profile_image'],
        // $_POST["mail"],
        // $_POST["password"]
      );
    } catch (InvalidFieldException $e) {
      if ($e instanceof UsernameWrongFormatException){
        $paramaters["username_wrong_format_error"] = UsernameWrongFormatException::USERNAME_MESSAGE_ERROR_WRONG_FORMAT;
      }
      elseif ($e instanceof FileTypeException) {
        $paramaters["file_type_error"] = FileTypeException::FILE_MESSAGE_ERROR_TYPE_FILE;
      }
    }
    break;
```

Am I missing something? I'm beginning with exceptions.

Sorry I'm adding more details here so like I said If I use the parent exception everything is working fine but its not my goal because I have many exceptions that inherit of the parent allowing me to check which exceptions has be thrown in the `index.php` thanks to the instanceof property.

The child class seems to not be  recognize at all by PHP and I don't understand why because when I click on the namespace it lead me to the right one making me think that composer as vscode knows where the class is

Comment: What do you mean by "seems to not be recognize" exactly? Is there an error when you run the code? Or unexpected behaviour? Please try to be more precise about the issue.

Comment: @ADyson I have this error :
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "Exceptions\UsernameWrongFormatException" not found

I thought perhaps its because I have too many class in one file so perhaps I should have one class per file ? I'm trying to see if in PSR rules they're is something about it.

Comment: [The use statement does not load the class file. You have to do this with the require/include statement or by using an autoload function.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#114265)

Comment: `I thought perhaps its because I have too many class in one file`...no, there's no limit on that. PHP doesn't care how big your files are, I don't know where you got that idea from. Even if there is some guidance about it in PSR, PHP doesn't enforce those rules. PSR is just a set of suggestions to help make your code more organised and readable, it's not rules that PHP cares about.

Comment: So if the class isn't found after you moved it to a separate file then, as Shingo's comment alludes to, it'll be because you haven't included that other file into your main script, so PHP cannot see that code when it runs.

Comment: I'm using the composer autoloader in the index.php so I dont need to use the require property each time that I need a class

Comment: Well, by the looks of it, it hasn't found the file properly in this case, so you'll need to investigate why. Or just move the class back into another file again, one which is definitely being autoloaded.

Comment: Ok I'll investigate and come later to post what I've done thanks.

Comment: If you moved a file, `composer dump-autoload` should help

Comment: @brombeer yeah I done it but nothing I change I'll update the post later when I'll find something

Comment: As promise I'm back and I haven't found a solution for it so I create a file for each exception and catch them in their own catch block. 

I'm still gonna try to have one file with all exception on it so I'll update the post later at the end of week.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't found a better solution than create a file for each exception and catch them in their own catch block